# Why do different ffmpeg runs generates different files?

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm using ffmpeg to encode yuv videos into h.264 mp4 files. However, when I run the same command with the same input file I get different outputs.
There is no visible difference when I play the 2 output files, but they are not exactly the same size and a binary comparison shows they are completely different.
How can the same software with the same parameters generate different results on different runs on the same machine?

Comment: Share command and logs of runs producing different output.

Comment: MP4 has some fields that include the current time stamp.